# Pagelayout using different version of masterpage

Tags: page-layout, inheritance, caching, custom-masterpage

I have made 3 custom pagelayouts, 2 of them just inherit the correct version of the masterpage whilst the last one uses the same masterpage, but an older version of it.

It contains the exact same divs and controls as the masterpage the other 2 pagelayouts inherit, but not the same HTML structure. I can't seem to find the source of this evil.

I tried deleting the cache, rebuild and redeploy the custom masterpage etc. Nothing has helped so far.

How come this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all the master pages use the same `~masterurl/default.master` token? It could be that you've got one that is using the custom master page (`~masterurl/custom.master`)

Could your page have been detached from it's page layout (via SharePoint Designer)? That might do it as well. Essentially, your page would be built into a stand alone page.

Answer (score 1):

Is the page that uses the third page layout 'customized' (unghosted) by any chance? What happens if you create a brand new page that uses the third page layout?

Comment: Then the new page will also use the wrong version of the masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

if unghosting / customizing was not the root of the evil, you can try to remove any reference from the page layout in your existing pages, delete the dreaded page layout and reprovision it again.

Alternatively, are you sure you don't have output caching with a long expiration date ? It could be cached client side and any change on the server wouldn't be reflected.